# Make Apache 2.4 folder visible in File Explorer for local Network

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a site hosted on a Apache 2.4 server. Is there a way to make a particular folder on that site, like /var/www/uploads/, visible in File Explorer for people in the local Network, so they can upload files to that folder by copy & pasting?

Comment: Install a service that provides a compatible file sharing protocol on the server runnjng Apache; typical are samba for cifs/smb or a WebDAV service in Apache